# Operator += cannot be applied

Tags: c#

I am creating a C# WinForms app that should closes the application using the voice command "exit".

However it gives me an exception:

> Operator += cannnot be applied to operands of System speech or main method

In this code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SpeechRecognitionEngine sRecongize = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Compiler error here:
        sRecongize += sRecongize_SpeechRecognized;
    }

    private void sRecongize_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result.Text == "exit")
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I subscribe to an event?

Comment: You are missing the event name. The line should probably read `sRecognize.OnSomeEventName += sRecognize_SpeechRecognized;`

Answer (score 5):

You need to subscribe to a specific event, in this case [`SpeechRecognized`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.speechrecognized(v=vs.110).aspx), not the entire class:

```
sRecongize.SpeechRecognized += sRecongize_SpeechRecognized;
```